# how to set api to hit after 30 minutes of login in android

Tags: android, runnable

I am working on an app & I need to hit api after 30 minutes when the user login (either by google/facebook). No matters on which activity I am currently but I have to hit api just after 30 minutes.

I tried

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              //API Hit
        }
    }, 1800000);
```

Is there a way out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a service to send that data and use AlarmManager with the PendingIntent for that Service to launch after 30 mins. Here's an example code:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent m_intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, m_intent, 0);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30, pi);
```

Comment: Thanks for ans ...Could you please elaborate a little

Comment: I have created a service extends IntentService n hiting API in that. n BatService is current Activity right? and where you are hiting pending Intent?

Comment: Your service should extend `Service` and BatService.this is basically current `context` and I'm passing `pi` to `alarm.set` (fixed the code).

Comment: If this solved your issue, mark this as accepted answer. Otherwise, let us know where you're struck.

Comment: Sure, but let me test it once. Server is not working currently. I will mark accepted as soon as I got response else thnx